# Using Jersey Test Framework produces NullPointerException during JerseyTest constructor

Tags: exception, pointers, testing, null, jersey

I am using Jersey Test Framework, however, even before the code gets to my test, the JerseyTest constructor fails with:

```
Mar 06, 2014 6:40:44 PM org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler initialize
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version Jersey: 2.6 2014-02-18 21:52:53...

A MultiException has 3 exceptions.  They are:
1. java.lang.NullPointerException
2. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: method inject on com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$App
3. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: create on org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory
MultiException stack 1 of 3
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractJAXBProvider.setConfiguration(AbstractJAXBProvider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.invoke(ReflectionHelper.java:1017)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.methodMe(ClazzCreator.java:375)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:428)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:456)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.PerLookupContext.findOrCreate(PerLookupContext.java:69)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2445)
```

My test is very simple:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({"/applicationContext-test.xml"})
public class BidAPITest extends JerseyTest {

    @Override
    protected Application configure() {
        return new ResourceConfig(BidAPI.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void testCreate() {
        final BidDocument
            bid =
                target(BidAPI.PATH)
                    .request()
                    .post(
                        Entity.entity("", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE),
                        BidDocument.class
                    );

        System.out.println(bid);
    }
}
```

The actual failure occurs while setConfiguration is being invoked in AbstractJAXBProvider.  The actual line which fails in the JettyTest constructor is:

```
public ComponentModelValidator(ServiceLocator locator) {
    validators = Lists.newArrayList();
    validators.add(new ResourceValidator());
    /* -FAILS-> */ validators.add(new RuntimeResourceModelValidator(locator.getService(MessageBodyWorkers.class)));
    validators.add(new ResourceMethodValidator(locator));
    validators.add(new InvocableValidator());
}
```

Any ideas before I start ripping apart my application?

Thanks.
-AP_

Comment: There is a similar question that might help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14487582/getting-data-through-rest-webservice-gives-exception
Did you actually find the issue in the end?

Comment: No, I did not.  I have not had a chance to come back to this.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same problem using Spring 3.2.6 & Jersey 2.6.
I solved it by upgrading Jersey to version 2.9.1.

Also make sure you are using this dependency to make spring 3 & jersey coexist :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.1</version>
    <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
     </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: What to do in case you can not use any higher version of Jersey than 2.6? I have to use Java SE 6 and only until version 2.6, Jersey was compiled with Java SE 6. Now almost all Jersey components are compiled with Java SE 7 target. So, version 2.9.1 does not work with Java SE 7, unfortunately.