# Getting a 404 error when calling Get Request in Java

Tags: java, rest

I trying to call a GET request on a specific API endpoint in order to get product information. I have two netbeans projects, one for the server in which i have my end points and another for my GUI.

In my GUI class I have button to GET product information and I am trying to put the returned JSON into a TextArea in Swing. I have two classes within my GUI project, one for a client get that returns the json as a string and another class for my jFrame.

> Strangely, when i call my client class on button click i get :
>   !Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed >: HTTP error code : 404

When I simply run the client class by itself i do get my expected output in the console, not sure how to fix this if anyone could help?

ClientCall.java

```
public class ClientCall{

String tempOut = "";

public String getProduct() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException  {

    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(
            "http://localhost:8080/api/product/1");
    getRequest.addHeader("accept", "application/json");

    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(getRequest);

    if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
               + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
    }

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
             new InputStreamReader((response.getEntity().getContent())));

    String output;
    System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
    while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(output);
    }
    tempOut = output;
    httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();

    return tempOut;
}

/*public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
    ClientCall c = new ClientCall();
    System.out.println(c.getProduct());
}*/
```

}

GUI.java

```
private void jButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    System.out.print("!");
    try {
        System.out.println(cc.getProduct());

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(GetDetailsGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Note, In my code above (GUI) i am simply outputting the response, even this doesnt work.

Comment: Is `"http://localhost:8080/api/product/1` running?

Comment: Yup, localhost is running, strange thing is the Client class outputs what I want when run it as a standalone but when called my the GUI class it produces that error

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14487582/getting-data-through-rest-webservice-gives-exception